Can Ceres-solver be utilised on an RTOS such as ThreadX?
Currently investigating if we can use the combo Eigen/Ceres-solver in an embedded environment.
We'd be x-compiling to an STM32 ARM architecture running ThreadX RTOS, building the binaries using an IAR toolchain.
But ThreadX brings to the table its own threading model, including mutexes etc.
There is no std::mutex and the mere inclusion of header <thread> will stop the build.
So unless I can build Ceres in a non-multithreaded way, I think this project is dead in the water.
I have had a look at how Ceres is configured and none of the options leap out.

It transpires that - in my case - just using Ceres' tiny_solver.h provides all that I need, as such rendering our requirements on the Ceres library into a non-threaded, header-only library.
